# Allowed energies for relativistic and non-relativistic bound states in quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, schroedinger-equation, dirac-equation

I'm studying the Dirac equation in one spatial dimension, more specifically bound states. My question is: given a quantum system (a potential well for example), whose bound states have the allowed energies $E^S_{n}$ obtained from solving the Schrodinger equation and the energy levels $E^D_n$ obtained from solving the Dirac equation, which of these should be bigger as $n$ increases and why?

Comment: Do you have any thoughts or ideas about the answer yourself?